# The app settings value can not be updated using the kudu API call in azure function App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azureportal, kudu

I have used visual studio 2019. I have used 2 API calls
I referred to the document below:

Use Kudu API to change function.json https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API

1.PUT https://{functionAppName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/{pathToFunction.json}, Headers: If-Match:"*", Body: new function.json content
Then send the request to apply changes

2.POST https://{functionAppName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/functions/synctriggers
Both apis are return success status code

**status code:**

[image: status result]
**API1** gives 204 or 201 which means the document successfully updated

**API2** gives 201 which means the document successfully done the  sync trigger to save the file modification

after the function is completed then I refresh the page the file is not changed
[image: function.json]

**code below:**

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var creds = "credentials";
            var credentials = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(creds);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(credentials));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("If-Match", "*");
            var data = new List<ChangeData>
                 {
                     new ChangeData{schedule="125255"}
                 };
            string json = "{'schedule':'*/48 * * * * *'}";
            var customerJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            var content = new StringContent(customerJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = client.PutAsync("https://********.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/home/site/wwwroot/Function7/function.json", content);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Result);
            /// var errorMessage = response..ToString();

            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://******.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/functions/synctriggers"))
            {
                var base64authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("basestring"));
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Basic {base64authorization}");

                var response3 = await client.SendAsync(request);
                Console.WriteLine(response3);
            }
```

I want to change schedule value in the function.json

Comment: Could you please describe your issue in detail? What do you want to update?

Comment: ok I edit the question

Comment: COuld you please check if you function is read modle?

Comment: in the Azure portal, it shows the notification that "Your app is currently in read-only mode because you are running from a package file. To make any changes update the content in your zip file and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting."but i don't know how to fix this

Comment: In the mode, we cannot update any file in function. If you want to update your function, we need to deploy it again.

Comment: u said that publish again from the visual studio?

Comment: yeah. your understanding is right.

Comment: again no changes in file

Comment: Could you please how you change it?

Comment: I publish again but no changes in function.json

Comment: Deployed by func cmd, you also can modify file by kudu api. Could you accept my solution as answer? Tks.

Comment: I marked the answer in another question, please check. I can't change the value using kudu API call but in the portal, I can change the value only

Comment: can you refer me that how to change the content kudu API call I tried this

Answer (score 1):

## Newest

The previous version of azure function can modify the file through the run-from-package configuration. Now the function app directly released through vs2019 does not support this operation.

To achieve your needs, we can use the command line to publish. The specific steps are in your other post, you need to help more forum users.

```
func azure functionapp publish function_app_name --csharp --nozip --force
```

[How to change content dynamically after function is called in Azure function app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66915767/how-to-change-content-dynamically-after-function-is-called-in-azure-function-app)

---

> You want to change schedule value in the function.json.

1. As I replied in another post of yours, it doesn't make sense, but I also have a way（ by `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT`） for you to make changes.
2. The main reason is that modifying the json file will not recompile our FunctionApp1.dll file, as shown in the figure below.

[image]

[How to change content dynamically after function is called in Azure function app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66915767/how-to-change-content-dynamically-after-function-is-called-in-azure-function-app)

## Why do you have such a demand?

I guess you have created a Function App on Azure Portal, so you think you can modify the configuration by modifying function.json, but this is not the case.

Because the function app created on the portal generates a `.csx` file, it does not end up running a `.dll`, which is the essential difference.

[image]

[image]